# "Expanding" a List of Lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have a table (a list of lists) of a datatype SFeld. SFeld is either a Int or a List of Ints

```
data SFeld = E Int | M [Int]

type STable = [[SFeld]]
```

I want to define a function `expandM :: STable -> [STable]` that takes a STable and "expands" every M in it, so that a List of new STables is created for every value in the M List. Sounds very confusing so here is an example:

```
>> expandM [[E 1,M [1,2]],[M [2,3],E 2,E 4],[E 5]] = 

                 [ [[E 1,E 1],[E 2,E 2,E 4],[E 5]]
                 , [[E 1,E 2],[E 2,E 2,E 4],[E 5]]
                 , [[E 1,E 1],[E 3,E 2,E 4],[E 5]]
                 , [[E 1,E 2],[E 3,E 2,E 4],[E 5]]
                 ]
```

How would I implement a function like this?

Comment: Not a solution, but a comment.  Perhaps you should define your `STable` as a list of tuples rather than a list of lists, since, as far as  I see, the inner list is always two elements long. It will move some error checking from run time to compile time.  Also I would consider using two different types for the `M` part and for the `E` part, since their meaning seem to me totally different.

Comment: The list can be longer than two. I just used two elements in the example to make it more readable. The M value is supposed to be a list of possible E values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting together all the possible combinations from items in a list is the bind operator `>>=` for the `Monad []` instance. Specialized for lists it has the type

```
(>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
```

For every item `a` in the list, it runs the function `a -> [b]` to figure out all the possibilities and collects those possibilities in the resulting list `[b]`. The basic function we want to work with matches this signature; it computes all the possible `SFeld`s from an initial `SFeld`.

```
expandSFeld :: SFeld -> [SFeld]
expandSFeld (E x)  = [E x]
expandSFeld (M xs) = map E xs
```

The `SFeld`s are being held in an existing structure, an `STable` which is a list of lists of `SFeld`s. We'd like to use the `Monad []` instance's bind on an `STable` without changing the structure of the table. In general, the `Traverable` class describes those structures that can be preserved so that a `Monad`<sup>†</sup> operating inside the structure can be moved to the outside of the structure.

```
                                     -- v-------------v    flips Traverable from outside to inside      
sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
     -- flips Monad from inside to outside ^-------^
```

`Traversable` also includes a function, `mapM`, that maps a function `a -> m b` over a `t a` resulting in a `m (t b)`. The resulting `t b`s have the same structure as the initial `t a`.

```
mapM :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)
mapM k = sequence . fmap k
```

Lists have a `Traversable` instance. This means we can preserve the structure of a list while performing operations in some `Monad` on each item in the list. We can use this to perform the `expandSFeld` operation on each item in a row while preserving the structure of the row.

```
import Data.Traversable
import Prelude hiding (mapM)

expandSRow :: [SFeld] -> [[SFeld]]
expandSRow = mapM expandSFeld
```

And we can perform the `expandSRow` operation on each row in an `STable` while preserving the structure of the `STable`.

```
expandM :: STable -> [STable]
expandM = mapM expandSRow
```

The resulting `expandM` function returns every possible `STable` obtained by expanding all the `M`s.

```
expandM [[E 1,M [1,2]],[M [2,3],E 2]] 
[
  [[E 1,E 1],[E 2,E 2]],
  [[E 1,E 1],[E 3,E 2]],
  [[E 1,E 2],[E 2,E 2]],
  [[E 1,E 2],[E 3,E 2]]
]
```

<sup>†</sup> The functions from the `Traverable` class can be used more generally with any `Applicative` instead of any `Monad`.